# Сложное предложение с сочинительной и подчинительной союзной частью

Tags: сложное-предложение

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом И в следующем предложении?

*Те вещи, что я не постирала и он не забрал, лежат в гараже.*

Просто я привыкла, что если есть подлежащее и сказуемое, то нужна запятая. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В рассматриваемом предложении **два однородных придаточных**, соединённых союзом ***и***. Запятая между такими придаточными не ставится.

См. правило:

§ 119. В сложноподчиненных предложениях **с несколькими однородными придаточными** знаки препинания ставятся по правилам, действующим при отделении однородных членов простого предложения…

2. **Между двумя придаточными, соединенными одиночными соединительными или разделительными союзами *и, или, либо, да* (в значении «и»), запятая не ставится** (при этом подчинительный союз или союзное слово может и не повторяться): *Подходя к дому, я вспомнил, **что неподалеку в еловом перелеске с можжевельником не раз спугивал старого петуха-черныша и еще там жила матка с одним молодым петушком*** (Пришв.) — две придаточные части изъяснительные, соединенные союзом ***и***.

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не нужна, поскольку обе пары подлежащих и сказуемых относятся к одной придаточной части, начинающейся словом *что.*